# How to create .exe with C# winforms Application & MSSQL Database in Advanced Installer Architect

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm facing severe issue while creating **.exe** file of my **C# WinForms Application** using **Advanced Installer Architect**. I'm not getting to know how exactly to **create** an **exe file with MSSQL Database**.

**Kindly help me solve the issues:**

1. I want MSSQL Database to be installed automatically on the system if it doesn't exist.
2. I want to know what should be the datasource in my application while building it.
3. I also want the tables should be created automatically t the now installed MSSQL Server Database.

Kindly help me with this issue!

Comment: 1) You mean MS SQL Server, or the free light version? If the latter, see 3. 2) That depends on your database. Ever used Visual Studio? It can help connection to your database. 3) Have a look at Entity Framework Code First.

Comment: I've already developed the application but now I need to create exe file and deliver to the client

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio then you already have exe created.
visual studio is much smarter. and its creating exe every time we run our win form application.

you can find exe in your projectfolder/bin/debug/yourexe.exe